# What's the most comfortable way (for the dogs) to carry two chihuahua's outside?

Tags: dogs, multi-pet-families

We have three chihuahuas in our family, two of which are unable to walk down stairs so I often find myself having to carry them outside. They don't like to do anything outside, if the whole group isn't there and I don't like leaving them outside without supervision, even momentarily. So, I find myself having to carry both of them outside on one go, one on each hand.

What would be the optimal way to carry them so that they would feel as comfortable as possible on the way? Should I really be taking them outside one-by-one instead, and leaving the other two unattended for a moment, while I carry the third one?

Comment: alter the steps so they can navigate the stairs themselves?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Not an option at the moment, and not really the point of the question, the story is just one example where the need pops up.

Comment: Why are they unable to walk down the stairs?  It may be pertinent to the answer if it is a physical limitation.

Comment: @Chad One is too small and the other won't [walk on wooden material](http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/637/177) and has a small disability in terms of her movement.

Answer (score 5):

I own two dachshunds and have a 2-story home.  My office is upstairs and my dogs love to hang out with me.  Dachshunds are notorious for developing bad backs, so I try to prevent them from climbing the stairs. I have a large, flat-bottomed, metal-reinforced, wicker basket inside which I've laid a very thin cotton blanket.  My dogs know to lay on the blanket inside the basket, which I then pick up to carry them up or down the stairs.  We always keep the basket near the stairs.

Prior to owning the basket, we used a large dog bed to carry both hounds, but it was much heavier and bulkier than the basket.

I'm fairly sure my dachshunds are heavier and larger than 3 chihuahuas; the tail and head of one of them hangs over either end of the basket unless she curls up, which she often does.  You can check your local craft store for appropriately-sized wicker baskets, the availability and variety of which increase nearing Easter time.

Comment: We used a dog carrying bag for a while, but the smallest dog tends to jump out of it the moment he has the chance. Useful answer, anyhow.

Comment: @3ventic - and what is the problem with that?  Have you tried training him not to jump out until told?

Comment: Sounds like your dog does not enter the basket voluntarily. Mine have no problem with the task. You must make the basket an attractive option or use a closeable dog carrier.